# Where can I get a JSON or CSV file with the average Bitcoin USD value for each day since it was announced?

Tags: finance, historical, json, csv, trade

I've just spent several days downloading and loading in what turned out to be 10+ GB of garbage data. All I wanted was to know the current USD (average) market value for each day (not minute/hour) since the beginning. Simply to make some basic states for myself.

That is, not some paid/registration "API". Just a simple resource somewhere trustworthy. It's not a lot of data at all; not even ~4,000 days have passed since Bitcoin was announced, and the first marketplaces probably didn't appear right away. (The data I was trying to juggle was every single transaction ever performed on every exchange.)